# NumPy IFFT introducing black bars in OaA Convolution Algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, convolution

I'm having trouble diagnosing and fixing this error. I'm trying to write the OaA algorithm, described [in this paper](https://etd.ohiolink.edu/!etd.send_file?accession=wright1432747175&disposition=inline#page=33).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

""" Quick implementation of several convolution algorithms to compare times 
"""

import numpy as np
import _kernel
from tqdm import trange, tqdm
from PIL import Image
from scipy.misc import imsave
from time import time, sleep


class convolve(object):
    """ contains methods to convolve two images """
    def __init__(self, image_array, kernel, back_same_size=True):
        self.array = image_array
        self.kernel = kernel

        # Store these values as they will be accessed a _lot_
        self.__rangeX_ = self.array.shape[0]
        self.__rangeY_ = self.array.shape[1]
        self.__rangeKX_ = self.kernel.shape[0]
        self.__rangeKY_ = self.kernel.shape[1]

        # Ensure the kernel is suitable to convolve the image
        if (self.__rangeKX_ >= self.__rangeX_ or \
            self.__rangeKY_ >= self.__rangeY_):
            raise ValueError('Must submit suitably-sized arrays')

        if (back_same_size):
            # pad array for convolution
            self.__offsetX_ = self.__rangeKX_ // 2
            self.__offsetY_ = self.__rangeKY_ // 2
         
            self.array = np.lib.pad(self.array,      \
                [(self.__offsetY_, self.__offsetY_), \
                 (self.__offsetX_, self.__offsetX_)],\
                 mode='constant', constant_values=0)

            # Update these
            self.__rangeX_ = self.array.shape[0]
            self.__rangeY_ = self.array.shape[1]
        else:
            self.__offsetX_ = 0
            self.__offsetY_ = 0

        # to be returned instead of the originals
        self.__arr_ = np.zeros([self.__rangeX_, self.__rangeY_])\

    def spaceConv(self):
        """ normal convolution, O(N^2*n^2). This is usually too slow """

        # this is the O(N^2) part of this algorithm
        for i in trange(self.__rangeX_):
            for j in xrange(self.__rangeY_):
                # Now the O(n^2) portion
                total = 0.0
                for k in xrange(self.__rangeKX_):
                    for t in xrange(self.__rangeKY_):
                        total += \
                  self.kernel[k][t] * self.array[i+k][j+t]

                # Update entry in self.__arr_, which is to be returned
                # http://stackoverflow.com/a/38320467/3928184
                self.__arr_[i][j] = total

        return self.__arr_[self.__offsetX_\
                           :self.__rangeX_ - self.__offsetX_,\
                           self.__offsetY_\
                           :self.__rangeY_ - self.__offsetY_]

    def spaceConvDot(self):
        """ Exactly the same as the former method """

        def dot(ind, jnd):
            """ perform a simple 'dot product' between the 2 
            dimensional image subsets. """
            total = 0.0

            # This is the O(n^2) part of the algorithm
            for k in xrange(self.__rangeKX_):
                for t in xrange(self.__rangeKY_):
                    total += \
              self.kernel[k][t] * self.array[k + ind, t + jnd]
            return total
     
        # this is the O(N^2) part of the algorithm
        for i in trange(self.__rangeX_):
            for j in xrange(self.__rangeY_):
                self.__arr_[i][j] = dot(i, j)
     
        return self.__arr_[self.__offsetX_\
                           :self.__rangeX_ - self.__offsetX_,\
                           self.__offsetY_\
                           :self.__rangeY_ - self.__offsetY_]

    def OAconv(self):
        """ faster convolution algorithm, O(N^2*log(n)). """
        from numpy.fft import fft2 as FFT, ifft2 as iFFT

        # solve for the total padding along each axis
        diffX = (self.__rangeKX_ - self.__rangeX_ +  \
                 self.__rangeKX_ * (self.__rangeX_ //\
                 self.__rangeKX_)) % self.__rangeKX_
        
        diffY = (self.__rangeKY_ - self.__rangeY_ +  \
                 self.__rangeKY_ * (self.__rangeY_ //\
                 self.__rangeKY_)) % self.__rangeKY_

        # padding on each side, i.e. left, right, top and bottom; 
        # centered as well as possible
        right = diffX // 2
        left = diffX - right
        bottom = diffY // 2
        top = diffY - bottom

        # pad the array
        self.array = np.lib.pad(self.array,                 \
                            ((left, right), (top, bottom)), \
                           mode='constant', constant_values=0)

        divX = self.array.shape[0] / float(self.__rangeKX_)
        divY = self.array.shape[1] / float(self.__rangeKY_)

        # Let's just make sure...
        if not (divX % 1.0 == 0.0 or divY % 1.0 == 0.0):
            raise ValueError('Image not partitionable (?)')
        else:
            divX = int(divX)
            divY = int(divY)

        # a list of tuples to partition the array by
        subsets = [(i*self.__rangeKX_, (i + 1)*self.__rangeKX_,\
                    j*self.__rangeKY_, (j + 1)*self.__rangeKY_)\
                        for i in xrange(divX)                  \
                        for j in xrange(divY)]

        # padding for individual blocks in the subsets list
        padX = self.__rangeKX_ // 2
        padY = self.__rangeKY_ // 2

        self.__arr_ = np.lib.pad(self.__arr_,              \
                            ((left + padX, right + padX),  \
                             (top + padY, bottom + padY)), \
                           mode='constant', constant_values=0)

        kernel = np.pad(self.kernel,                  \
                        [(padY, padY), (padX, padX)], \
                      mode='constant', constant_values=0)

        # We only need to do this once
        trans_kernel = FFT(kernel)

        # transform each partition and OA on conv_image
        for tup in tqdm(subsets):
            # slice and pad the array subset
            subset = self.array[tup[0]:tup[1], tup[2]:tup[3]]

            subset = np.lib.pad(subset,      \
                [(padY, padY), (padX, padX)],\
                mode='constant', constant_values=0)

            trans_subset = FFT(subset)

            # multiply the two arrays entrywise
            subset = trans_kernel * trans_subset
            space = iFFT(subset).real

            # overlap with indices and add them together
            self.__arr_[tup[0]:tup[1] + 2 * padX, \
                        tup[2]:tup[3] + 2 * padY] += space

        # crop image and get it back, convolved
        return self.__arr_[self.__offsetX_ + padX + left   \
                           :padX + left + self.__rangeX_   \
                              - self.__offsetX_,           \
                           self.__offsetY_ + padY + bottom \
                           :padY + bottom + self.__rangeY_ \
                              - self.__offsetY_]

    def OSconv(self):
        """ Convolve an image using OS """
        from numpy.fft import fft2 as FFT, ifft2 as iFFT
        pass

    def builtin(self):
        """ Convolves using SciPy's convolution function - extremely
        fast """
        from scipy.ndimage.filters import convolve
        return convolve(self.array, self.kernel)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        import pyplot as plt
    except ImportError:
        import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    image = np.array(Image.open('spider.jpg'))

    image = np.rot90(np.rot90(np.rot90(image.T[0])))

    times = []

    #for i in range(3, 21, 2):
    kern = _kernel.Kernel()
    kern = kern.Kg2(11, 11, sigma=2.5, muX=0.0, muY=0.0)
    kern /= np.sum(kern)        # normalize volume

    conv = convolve(image, kern)
    #
    #    # Time the result of increasing kernel size
    #    _start = time()
    convolved = conv.OAconv()
    #convolved = conv.builtin()
    #    _end = time()
    #    times.append(_end - _start)

    #x = np.array(range(3, 21, 2))
    #plt.plot(range(3, 21, 2), times)
    #plt.title('Kernel Size vs. spaceConv time', fontsize=12)
    #plt.xlabel('Kernel Size (px)', fontsize=12)
    #plt.ylabel('Time (s)', fontsize=12)
    #plt.xticks(x, x)
    #plt.show()

    #conv = convolve(image[:2*kern.shape[0],:5*kern.shape[1]], kern)

    plt.imshow(convolved, interpolation='none', cmap='gray')
    plt.show()
    #imsave('spider2', convolved, format='png')
```

But now, when I call it, I get black bars in a test image as follows:

[image]

Here's an example Gaussian kernel I am using.

```
[[ 0.          0.02390753  0.03476507  0.02390753  0.        ]
 [ 0.02390753  0.06241541  0.07990366  0.06241541  0.02390753]
 [ 0.03476507  0.07990366  0.10040324  0.07990366  0.03476507]
 [ 0.02390753  0.06241541  0.07990366  0.06241541  0.02390753]
 [ 0.          0.02390753  0.03476507  0.02390753  0.        ]]
```

I believe I've narrowed the problem down to the multiplication and IFFT

```
space = np.real(IFFT(transformed_kernel*transformed_subset))
```

I think it has something to do with the IFFT of discrete Gaussian kernel (for some reason). It's odd because if I just plot

```
space = np.real(IFFT(transformed_subset))
```

I get the following (**no black bars, and it pieces it back together fine**):

[image: okay]

And if I plot the opposite, i.e.

```
space = np.real(IFFT(transformed_kernel))
```

I **again get no black bars**, and it appears to place them in the right places.

[image]

What am I missing? I've been staring at this for days, editing indices and whatnot, but I can't get rid of this tessellation :(

Comment: maybe adding the script you use to produce the results would help to understand what exactly you are doing and make it easier to start out with your problem

Comment: @ead I've added the whole script. Everything is available on github as well: https://github.com/bjd2385/fftconvolve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is, that your kernel seems to be in the middle:

[image: wrong kernel]

But it is not - there is also a shift (11, 11) involved, which becomes obvious when you look at the results of the convolution. The center of your kernel should be in (0,0) and (because of modulo) your kernel should look like this:

[image: right kernel]

So I changed your code a little (sorry never used np so much, but I hope you 
can get the gist):

```
 ... your code ...
 kernel = np.pad(self.kernel,                  \
                        [(padY, padY), (padX, padX)], \
                      mode='constant', constant_values=0)
 #Move the kernel center to the origin:                   
 new_kernel=np.full_like(kernel, 0)
 X,Y=kernel.shape
 X_2=X//2
 Y_2=Y//2
 for x in xrange(X):
     for y in xrange(Y):
          n_x=(x+X_2)%X
          n_y=(y+Y_2)%Y        
          new_kernel[n_x,n_y]=kernel[x,y]


  # We only need to do this once          
  trans_kernel = FFT(new_kernel)# take the transform of the shifted kernel
  .... your code ......
```

And voilà:

[image: result]

There is no black grid!

Comment: THANK YOU. This makes so much sense too! It's also neat because, unless you're using larger kernels, you still get defects unless the kernel dimensions are even in size, so 8x8 or 10x10, as opposed to odd for the more common (but slow) spaceConv. But it works! Thank you so much!